# (updated) How to stop bodies after collision box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-development

how to stopped the forces acting **AFTER** the collision of a dynamic body with a dynamic body?
[image]

I expect that at the moment of collision, one body will be able to move body2, and after the collision, body2 will stop.
I tried really many times to solve this with ContactListener, ground friction and player active states. Unfortunately, I have not been able to solve this. Does anyone know how this should work?

I don't see the point in attaching the code, but I'll do it anyway:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
  ... 
  Player player;
  Player player2;
  
  @Override 
  public void show() {
    ... 
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0f), true);
    
    player = new Player(world);
    player2 = new Player(world);
    
    moveDirection = new MoveDirection(player);
    shotDirection = new ShotDirection(player);
    ... 
  }
  
  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2); 
    player.update();
    player2.update();
    ... 
  }
  ... 
}
```

```
public class Player {
  private final float PIXELS_TO_METERS = 100f;  
  private Sprite sprite;
  private World world;
  private Body body;
  ... 
  
  public Body getBody() 
  public void createBody() {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.position.set(
      sprite.getX() / PIXELS_TO_METERS, 
      sprite.getY() / PIXELS_TO_METERS 
    );
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius((long) (20) / PIXELS_TO_METERS);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.1f; 
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    shape.dispose();  
  }  
  public void update() {
    if(!isBodyCreated) {
      createBody();
      isBodyCreated = true;
    }
    //Previously used:
    /*if(!isActive()) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    }*/
    ... 
  }
  ... 
}
```

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** Ok, I found a solution, but it works with a delay, what can I do to fix it?
[image]

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
  ...
  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {
    world.step(1f/60f, 6, 2); 
    player.update();
    player2.update();
    ...
  } 
  ... 
} 

public class MoveDirection extends Actor {
  ... 
  addListener(new InputListener() {
    ... 
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {   
      ... 
      player.setActive(true);
      ... 
    } 
    ... 
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
      ... 
      player.setActive(false); 
      player.getBody().setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    } 
  ... 
} 

public class Player {
  private boolean active = false;
  ... 
  public void createBody() {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    bodyDef.position.set(
      (sprite.getX()) / PIXELS_TO_METERS, 
      (sprite.getY()) / PIXELS_TO_METERS 
    );
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius((long) (20) / PIXELS_TO_METERS);
    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.1f; 
    //fixtureDef.restitution = 0; 
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    shape.dispose();  
    body.setBullet(true);
    body.setUserData("player");
  }  
  public void setActive(boolean bool) {
    this.active = bool;
  }
  public boolean isActive() {
    return this.active;
  }  
  public boolean isContact() {
    boolean isContact = false;
    for(Contact contact : world.getContactList()) {
      if((contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == this.body || contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == this.body) && (contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData() == "player" && contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData() == "player")) {
        isContact = true;
        break;
      } 
    }
    return isContact; 
  } 
  public void update() {
    ... 
    if(!isContact() && !isActive()) {
      body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, did you find a better solution. i want to stop character after collision but its better if they slid against each other.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got any experience with box2d, so I can not give a detailed answer. But perhaps this is where the EndContact and PostSolve methods are ment to be implemented.

https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy